# Install perl module Net:SSH2 on redhat/centos 7

Tags: perl, redhat, libssh2

As the title says I am trying to install the perl module perl-Net-SSH2. I have tried via yum but get an error that no package is available.

`yum install perl-Net-SSH2`

I have tried by downloading an rpm file but the only one I can find is for el6 and it complains about the version of perl

`yum localinstall perl-Net-SSH2-0.45-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.10.1)`

I have tried downloading the source code but get told "Unable to find a working version of library ssh2 in the following directories" even though it is installed. (via yum install libssh2 libssh2-devel)

I have tried via cpan but get the same error "Unable to find a working version of library ssh2 in the following directories"

Any ideas? Google is very sketchy on this and only

Comment: Have you tried `cpan Net::SSH2` or `cpanm Net::SSH2`?

Comment: Yeah, it was getting the same error as when I compiled from source, which was to say it couldn't find libssh2. This was actually an incorrect error because the real issue was gcc was not installed. When I installed this I was able to compile it. I never tried via cpan after that but I presume it would have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I solved this while writing the question. Seeing as information on this is limited I thought it would be worth posting the question anyway. The error message was giving the wrong information in that it was actually gcc that was missing, not libssh2. These are the steps I followed. I've tried to make it as verbatim as possible. I have not verified all these modules are required but this is what I installed before compiling it.

```
yum install libssh2 libssh2-devel
yum install openssl openssl-devel
yum install perl-Net-SSLeay
yum install gcc

Search for Net::SSH2 in google    
Click the link "Net::SSH2 - search.cpan.org"
Download source code (tar.gz file)
Copy it to your redhat 7 machine

tar -xvf Net-SSH2-0.62.tar.gz 
cd Net-SSH2-x.xx
perl Makefile.PL
make
make install
```

Should all be working now, test it with

```
perl -e 'use Net::SSH2;'
```